# Structure deference not working?

Tags: c++11, raii

Why isn't the following valid?

```
bool trigger(t_evt evt) const {
    std::shared_ptr<I> ptr = this->instance.lock();

    if (!ptr) {
        return false;
    }

    (ptr->*f)(evt); // -> causes a compilation error

    return true;
}
```

The error in english is something like that (I don't get it in english):

`'->*' : improper usage, left operand of type 'std::shared_ptr<ListenerCardsChange>'`

f is a pointer to a member function.

Note that `(*ptr.*f)(evt);` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `shared_ptr<T>`, and also `unique_ptr<T, D>`, do not overload `operator->*`. That's arguably a defect, but I haven't thought about it much and am not 100% sure that there isn't some reason for that.

Use the `(*ptr.*f)(evt)` syntax.

Comment: Is ->* a single operator? I though it was operator->(ptr) + operator*(f)

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook: If only there existed some kind of magic reference that would list C++ operators... (scratch that, then I'd still be creeping around 10k rep)

Comment: @KerrekSB [You mean like this one?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Operators)